# ENTITY FRAMEWORK OrderBy on Navigation Property (one-to-many)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my EF CodeFirst DB, I have two entities:

```
public class Prod
{
   public int ProductId {get;set;}
   ......
   ......
   public ICollection<ProdLang> ProdLangs {get;set;}
}

public class ProdLang
{
   public int ProdLangId {get;set;}
   public int LangId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
   ......
   ......
   public Product Product {get;set;}
}
```

With Eager Loading, I want to load my collection of Prod ordered by *ProdLang.Name* or *ProdLang.Description* for example, by a single *Langid*

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean load your collection of ProdLang ordered by ... (as opposed to collection of Prod)?  If so, this should work

```
public class Prod
{
    private ICollection<ProdLang> _prodLangs;
    public ICollection<ProdLang> ProdLangs 
    {
        get{ return _prodLangs.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList(); }
        set{ _prodLangs = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see ProductId property in your ProdLang class to join with Prod class, but I think that it exists.

So, you need to do :

```
var products = from p in Context.Prod.Set
               from pl in Context.ProdLang.Set
               where (p.ProductId == pl.ProductId)
               orderby (pl.Name)
               select p;
```

If you want to get ProdLang details, you can use a dynamic type:

```
var products = from p in Context.Prod.Set
               from pl in Context.ProdLang.Set
               where (p.ProductId == pl.ProductId)
               orderby (pl.Name)
               select new { Prod = p, ProdLang = pl };
```